# How to use tail -f with sound?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, audio, tail

I am trying to use tail -f and play a sound everytime a new line appears.

I tried this:

```
for i in tail -f myFile; do aplay alert.wav; done;
```

Which kinda worked, the output is:

```
Playing WAVE 'alert.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 22050 Hz, Mono
Playing WAVE 'alert.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 22050 Hz, Mono
Playing WAVE 'alert.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 22050 Hz, Mono
```

But after 3 times it stops, and I would like to print the tail -f result and not the aplay result.

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not on a Linux right now, but it should work like this:

```
tail -f yourFile | while read line ; do aplay alert.wav 2>&1 1>/dev/null ; echo $line ; done
```

On Mac OS X, I'm using the following successfully to print the system log:

```
tail -f /private/var/log/system.log | while read line; do printf "\a" ; echo $line ; done
```

Comment: Thanks it does work, I added aplay -q so it wont show the aplay results.

Comment: @foralsa Thanks. Since I don't know anything about `aplay` I just redirected its output. Should also work.